# Surjective Ring Homomorphism mapping center to center

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\phi$ be an onto ring homomorphism that maps say $R$ to $S$.

We know that under $\phi$, $Z(R)$ (the center of $R$, commutative elements under multiplication in $R$) get maps to a subset of $Z(S)$. Hence $\phi\big(Z(R)\big)\subseteq Z(S)$.

I can show that this holds, but I am struggling to come up with a counterexample showing that the image of $\phi$ under $Z(R)$ does not necessary have to be the entire set $Z(S)$. Namely $\phi\big(Z(R)\big)=Z(S)$ is not always true.

Then there must be some element say $\bar{t}\in Z(R)$ (since $\phi$ is onto, $\exists t\in R$ where $\phi(t)=\bar{t}$) such that for some $r\in R$, $tr\neq rt$ but $\bar{t}s=s\bar{t}$ for all $s\in S$. In another words, there must be some that is commutative in $S$ but the pullback of that element is not commutative in the domain.

This would be simple if $\phi$ is not onto, but it is.

If there's any logical error above, or any hints/advice, I would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Onto" i.e. surjective on sets, or an "epimorphism" in the category of rings? Because that is weaker, e.g. the inclusion $\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Q$ is an epimorphism, and there you'd have a counterexample.

Comment: I meant a surjective ring homomorphism, sorry for the confusion - will correct

Comment: You can take the free $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $F$ on two generators $x,y$ which is not commutative (it is the noncommutative analogue of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) and map it to the free commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra on two generators $x,y$, which is $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. The onto map $\phi:F \to \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ is the one induced by the identity on $\{ x,y\}$. Do you see how to show $\phi(Z(F)) \neq Z(\mathbb{R}[x,y])$?

Comment: Okay I can see that now, thanks!

Comment: @LucaCarai I would suggest that you post your comment as an answer. I would certainly give it a +1.

Comment: Sure, here you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the free $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $F$ on two generators $x,y$. It is a non-commutative algebra. You can think of it as the noncommutative analogue of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra)). Consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ which is the free commutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra on two generators $x,y$. Define the onto $\mathbb{R}$-algebra homomorphism $\phi:F \to \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ as the one induced by the identity on $\{ x,y\}$.

Then $Z(F)$ is given by the constant polynomials in $F$. Thus its image under $\phi$ is the  subring of constant polynomials of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Therefore 
$$\phi(Z(F))= \mathbb{R} \subsetneq  \mathbb{R}[x,y] =Z(\mathbb{R}[x,y]).$$

Clearly this still works with any commutative ring in place of $\mathbb{R}$.